# How to use vector of instances of class what are declared within namespace

Tags: c++, templates, vector, namespaces

I can`t cope with the following situation:

```
class someName
{ public:
vector<compound_objectNS::Compound_object*> loadObjectsFromFile(char* fileName);
}

namespace compound_objectNS
{ class Compound_object {here goes it`s defenition}.
}
```

I get error from isense: "*vector is not a template*"
What I am doing wrong?
Help me please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: with such basic problems (missing forward declarations, missing include files, missing namespace selectors, using char* instead of std::string, missing semicolon after class declaration, missing include guards) I sincerely recommend getting [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and I mean it honestly, it will save you a lot on your path forward.

Comment: yes, thank you for you suggestion, but I was unattentive and forgot about using std. As my working day is almost over sometimes stupid mistakes rise, but again thnx for suggestion ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include <vector>` before using `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Thank you! I ommited std: and that is why isense reported on error. I shall accept you answer after 20 min.

Comment: @spin_eight: If that was your sole problem, I highly recommend to copy+paste relevant code instead of transcribing it wrongly ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't write `using namespace std;` or some similar `using` directive, you should write `std::vector`. Or maybe you simply forgot the `#include <vector>` at the beginning of the file.

Also, you have to provide a declaration for `compound_objectNS` before declaring that `vector` (either a full definition, either a forward declaration).